# Integer Array list in Array Adapter in android

Tags: android, integer, android-arrayadapter, google-maps-android-api-2, android-spinner

I am working on google maps api, in which on map screen i want to give an option for a user to select map type through spinner. The return type of map option is integer so i am giving that value to spinner for selection through Integer Array. My code snippet is given below:

```
private GoogleMap mMap;

    int normMap = mMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL;
    int satelliteMap =mMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE;
    int terrainMap =mMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN; 
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.my_location_demo);
        spinnerOsversions = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter_state = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mapOptions);
    //Here it shows an error that Integer should not be passed to it,  want to send my mapType int array list to it   

          adapter_state.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

          spinnerOsversions.setAdapter(adapter_state);
          spinnerOsversions.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    }
```

Comment: and whats the problem? Please be specific and post stack trace..

Comment: You have to create a custom array adapter for using array list inside the adapter. You want code for that?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs this is what i am getting when i put Integer in ArrayAdapter: The constructor ArrayAdapter<Integer>(MyLocationActivity, int, int[]) is undefined

Comment: @MohammedAli can you please send me that custom code according to my described cpndition?

Comment: where you initialize `mapOptions` ?

Comment: @muhammad usman khan have you created a custom array adapter? If you want to use arraylist inside adapter it is better to use custom BaseAdapter.

Comment: @MohammedAli i haven't create a custom BaseAdapter. Can you please describe it with little bit custom code, so i can implement or amend it according to my condition.

Comment: what's the class name for your mapOptions variable. I am guessing mapType..tell me?

Comment: @MohammedAli i am just taking GoogleMap object and through this i am implementing mMap for my Map Options. It is a built-in method from Google API.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Class name for the variable mapOptions is YourClass, modify your code to:

```
ArrayAdapter<YourClass> adapter_state = new ArrayAdapter<YourClass>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mapOptions);
```

In the android [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html):
public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource, T[] objects)
Constructor
Parameters
context - The current context.
resource - The resource ID for a layout file containing a TextView to use when instantiating views.
objects - The objects to represent in the ListView.

Comment: <YourClass> is for my Activity class? On which i am implementing my spinner code?

Comment: Whats the class name for mapOptions..? and show me where you initiliazed mapOptions..

Comment: i am just taking GoogleMap object and through this i am implementing mMap for my Map Options. It is a built-in method from Google API. I am just passing data comming from mMap to my defined Integers and from there i am going to make an integer array list to display in spinner.

Comment: private GoogleMap mMap;

 int normMap = mMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL;
 int satelliteMap =mMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE;
 int terrainMap =mMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN;
 
 
 private int[] mapOptions = { normMap,satelliteMap,terrainMap };

Comment: try changing to ArrayAdapter<int>

Comment: see this for custom base adapter implementation...:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18348123/how-to-add-data-to-custom-baseadapter-for-listview-android and also this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333754/how-to-customize-listview-using-baseadapter