# Only one time last item of array is showing in listView in Android

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to add item in `ListView` dynamically but when I am using Custom adapter only last element of array is binding with `ListView`.

```
public class CustomAdapterForChat extends BaseAdapter 
{
    Context context;
    ArrayList<String>  message;
    LayoutInflater inflter;
    public CustomAdapterForChat(Context applicationContext, ArrayList<String> 
    message) 
    {//, int[] images,String[] statuses,String[] PhoneNumbers
        this.message=message;
        inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return message.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.senderlayout, null);
        TextView SenderMesssage=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.SenderMesssage);
        TextView time=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.timeOfmessage);
        SenderMesssage.setText(message.get(i));
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"); 
        Date date = new Date();
        time.setText(date.toString());
        return view;
    }
}
```

This is the code where I am calling custom adapter class, my array size is 5 and in custom Adapter constructor I am getting value properly but in `getView` method `i` is comming `0` only.

```
public class ChatPage extends ListActivity {

     String listItem[]={"Dell Inspiron", "HTC One X", "HTC Wildfire S", 
                        "HTC Sense", "HTC Sensation XE"};
     EditText et;
     List<String> arrayList;
     ImageView button;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_page);
         et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.writemessage);
         ArrayList values = new ArrayList();
         for (int i = 0; i < listItem.length; i++) {
             values.add(listItem[i]);
         }
         CustomAdapterForChat adapter = new CustomAdapterForChat(this,values);
         setListAdapter(adapter);
     }

     public void onClick(View view) {
          CustomAdapterForChat adapter = (CustomAdapterForChat) getListAdapter();
          String device;
          ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();
          for (int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++)
          {
              myList.add(adapter.getItem(i));
          }
          myList.add(et.getText().toString());
          CustomAdapterForChat adapternew = new CustomAdapterForChat(this,myList);
          setListAdapter(adapternew);

      }

 }
```

**ListView.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="tahatechno.tahatechno.ChatPage">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stackFromBottom="true">


        </ListView>
    </ScrollView>



    <include
        layout="@layout/type_message_area"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        />
 </LinearLayout>
 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Sender.XML**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/paddinfleftchatpage_"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_right_chat_page"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/SenderLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/SenderMesssage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_marginTop_chat_page"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
        android:padding="@dimen/text_view_padding"
        android:text="Android charting application xml ui design tutorial 
 with example. Android charting application xml ui design tutorial with 
example. Android charting application xml ui design tutorial with example. 
Android charting application xml ui design tutorial with example."
        android:textColor="#000" />



   </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/time"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:id="@+id/timeOfmessage"
        android:text="5:25 am"/>
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: show your code `loop`

Comment: what is the size ArrayList<String> message?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18348294/2725196

Comment: Please put your design xml file and java activity where adapter object created and attached.

Comment: please see my edit ,I have update xml and java activity

Answer (score -1):

your Loop is wrong. You are inserting the same item into the list for every time you run the loop. Make a singles instance of the object to be inserted in list. Or else paste the Code of Loop

Comment: Really?? this is not answer, this must be as comment

Comment: your Loop is wrong. You are inserting the same item into the list for every time you run the loop. Make a singles instance of the object to be inserted in list. Or else paste the Code of Loop


OK SIR AS YOU SAY.. @ShayanPourvatan

Comment: please check my edit ..i have added code of loop also.